# Some Tips to properly number SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql

As an Amateur PHP Developer I often have this problem of mixing sequences and variables.

SHORT :

So what would be the tips to keep in mind when writing a webpage that has many SQL queries.

I have thought of an idea of making a function but I am not sure if that would be of any good.

LONG:

The problem is I have a PHP page that has many sql queries which are followed by `result`, `row` , `row_number`, and `die()` if result unsuccessful after running the query.

I number them as `sql1`, `result1`, row1, error1, mysqlouput1 and sql2.... and so on..

When I add one more query after five or six days I have to go through the whole code to find out which was the last sequence used and take the next one, many times i just use the same and it creates strange problems.

The same problem with variables, as the same page is loading again and again with different `POST` and `GET` ids keeping track of variables is just too messy.

So what would be the tips to keep the code well sequenced, readable and variable names unique and understandable.

I have though of writing a function that takes the SQL as the input and gives the `result`, `row`, `row count`, and `error` as output.

What would you experienced people suggest ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't able to figure out with your details. It would be better if you post the code that you have

Comment: Strongly suggest separating out your queries into some sort of logic controller.

Answer (score 0):

at first you should really try to just use relevant names for your variables.
 Like if you are lookin for all the users use variables like `$sqlUsers`, `$queryUsers`, `$resultUsers`/`$usersArray`

The idea with the function would be one way to tackle the problem, as it no longer possible to code errors in the process itself, so if you do not want to switch to objectoriented programming I would probably choose that way.

Another way would be a mix, you could create only some classes in which you handle the database-interactions for specific domains. I.e. class userDataHandler would have the methods `getUserById()`, `getAllUsers()` et cetera. This way you would still have to write the querying process, but you know exactly where your queries are, have them in a structured way, there are no problems with naming your variables inside the methods, and your code doesn't get messy as you have different files for different domains -> separation of domainspecific code.

Can you explain your problem with the request-variables($_POST and $_GET) a little more? Why does your site get called with so many different variables, maybe you could structure your application a little better.